# ffmpeg extra lines between lines in drawtext textfile

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm getting extra lines when displaying a text file with drawtext. The original text.txt file looks like this:

[image]

But when I use with ffplay or ffmpeg using something like this:

```
ffplay -f lavfi "color=yellow:s=200x450,drawtext=textfile='text.txt':font='arial black':fontsize=16:line_spacing=0"
```

I get this:

[image]

https://i.ibb.co/L6XqG5Y/text.jpg

Does anyone know how to remove the extra lines between actual lines? I'm already using line_spacing=0

ffmpeg version: ffmpeg version N-113785-gfe340c3244-20240223 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers

OS: Windows 11 23H2

Comment: See these solutions for controlling the spacing: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213865/ffmpeg-drawtext-over-multiple-lines) and [link2](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/vr8ksq/help_needed_multiple_drawtext_with_the_same/).

Comment: Thank you @harrymc

Answer (score 2):

After some testing i found that Windows style line endings result in extra blank lines. Use Unix Style line endings in the textfile:

```
1\n
2\n
3\n
```

And not:

```
1\r\n
2\r\n
3\r\n
```

For testing use Notepad++ .Menu 'Edit' -> 'EOL Conversion' -> Unix (LF).

Programmatically there are many options. There is a commandline tool called dos2unix. Most programming and scripting languages are able to add Unix style line endings to text files out of the box

Comment: Interesting, but how do I actually do that?

Comment: For testing I used Notepad++ .Menu  'Edit' -> 'EOL Conversion' -> Unix (LF).
programmatically there are many options. There is a commandline tool called dos2unix. Most programming and scripting languages are able to add Unix style line endings to text files out of the box.

Comment: Ok, include this on your answer and I mark it as "solution"...

Answer (score 0):

I found out 2 possible solutions so far:

**1. Using negative values for the line_spacing option ex: line_spacing=-10**

**2. Converting the text file to unix style that uses only new line marker instead of new line + Enter like in Windows.**

Like Rens posted on his answer if you convert the text file to unix style you don't get this blank lines between each line.

I found a way to convert a text file to unix style using powersell like on this topic explained by Joey:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852682/convert-file-from-windows-to-unix-through-powershell-or-batch

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object {
  # get the contents and replace line breaks by U+000A
  $contents = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_) -replace "`r`n?", "`n"
  # create UTF-8 encoding without signature
  $utf8 = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false
  # write the text back
  [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_, $contents, $utf8)
}
```

For me the code was a litte bit different since I only needed to convert 1 file:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllText('c:\users\ricardo\desktop\text.txt',([IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\users\ricardo\desktop\text.txt') -replace "`r`n", "`n") ,(New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false))
```

I don't remember having to do any of these solutions before so this might not be a Windows problem but maybe an update of Windows or the ffmpeg version I'm using like listed before in the question.

Comment: With version 5.1.2 there is no issue, but with version 6.1.1 there is an issue with Windows new line style, and the spaces are larger than it should be even with Linux new line style. It looks like a bug.